# jquery - checkbox oncheck total will be updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I was trying to develop a checkbox using jQuery ..where oncheck total will be updated but when i uncheck it will be back as it is.. Here total updated with oncheck but it don't get back to total amount when i uncheck it .what could be possible error..anyone help please?

```
$('#vat').on('click',function(e){
    var vat = document.getElementById("vat").value;
    var total = document.getElementById("total").value;

    var sum = +total + +vat;
     document.getElementById("total").value =  sum;
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `#vat` is your input id

1- You need to use `change` instead of `click` *for radio and checkbox inputs*

2- check if checked or not by using `this.checked`

```
$('#vat').on('change',function(e){
    var sum = 0;
    var vat = document.getElementById("vat").value;
    var total = document.getElementById("total").value;
    if(this.checked === true){
       sum = total + vat;
    }else{
       sum = total - vat;
    }   
     document.getElementById("total").value =  sum;
  });
```

And while you're using and tagged jquery

```
   $('#vat').on('change',function(e){
        var sum = 0;
        var vat = parseInt($(this).val());
        var total = parseInt($("#total").val());
        if(this.checked === true){
           sum = total + vat;
        }else{
           sum = total - vat;
        }   
         $("#total").val(sum);
    });
```